# Excel 2016: Highlight unmatching rows in one column based on matching rows in an adjacent column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excel-2016, vba

I'm trying to come up with a function that will highlight any unmatching rows in one column based on matching adjacent rows in another column.

[image]

I'm having some trouble figuring out an effective way to do this with Conditional Formatting.

**Edit:**

I actually managed to figure out an answer as soon as I posted this.

In Conditional Formatting I wrote the function:

`(SUMIF($A$1:$A$7,A1,$B$1:$B$7)/COUNTIF($A$1:$A$7,A1))<>B1`

And it worked perfectly!

P.S.
I apologize for the poor wording on the question - I'm new to posting questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can you calrify why the three rows with `Apple` are highlighted but the two rows with `Banana` are not? Unless you only want to highlight rows with `Apple` and ignore all others?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad `Banana` is not highlighted because the numbers in Column B match.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad and why it is highlighted.  OP wants to highlight everywhere the name matches and the numbers do not.

Comment: If you wait a bit you will be able to post the answer and mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

us the following formula(Assuming Columns A:B as the Data):

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,"<>"&$B1)>0
```

Assign to: `$B:$B`

[image]

Comment: @pnuts you are correct, I missed that.  I went off the verbiage of the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to figure out an answer as soon as I posted this.

In Conditional Formatting I wrote the function:

```
(SUMIF($A$1:$A$7,A1,$B$1:$B$7)/COUNTIF($A$1:$A$7,A1))<>B1
```

And it worked perfectly!

Edit: And I apologize for the poor wording on the question - I'm new to posting questions on Stack Overflow.